# How to do GROUP BY with COUNT() and ordering by COUNT in influxdb?

Tags: analytics, influxdb

Im using **influxDb** and recording user visits to a dictionary pages and trying to get some queries working.

Like for example I'm trying to find out how to get a sorted set of headwords sorted by a number of visits to a particular word definition within some timeframe. So basically words sorted by a number of visits.

Im trying something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lookup GROUP BY word ORDER BY count_value LIMIT 100
```

^But it doesn't work. Error message is "Server returned error: error parsing query: only ORDER BY time supported at this time".

Is what im trying to do not achievable in **influxDb**?

Comment: can you show how your data is stored in influxdb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by the error that was returned

```
Server returned error: error parsing query: only ORDER BY time supported at this time
```

InfluxDB only supports `ORDER BY` time at the moment. To achieve the result that you're looking for you'd need to do the `ORDER BY` client side.

Comment: thx. yeah. I went with ELK stack which seems to work really good for this scenario.

Comment: If you are using Grafana, you can use "Limit" and "Sort By" transformations from the Transform tab